# Docker volume is not fully sync directory for one container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created simple project for Symfony4 based on php7.3+mariadb via docker-compose. I used Docker for Windows 10 (x64)
It works correctly at one machine but at laptop it doesn't sync correctly with container.

In root folder I have standard Symfony structure with docker files like:
- /config
- /public
- /src
....
- /env
- /docker
- .env
- docker-compose.yaml
...

My actions in Git Bash to start app:

1. docker-compose build

   - it works correctly, all actions were finished successfully
2. docker-compose up -d

   - it works correctly, both containers run successfully
3. docker-compose exec app bash

   - works correctly, console starts
4. ls

   - result is `docker env`
   - it syncs only 2 directories - docker and env
   - docker dir was synced not in full mode - only subdirectories structure without files

I tried to detect what reason can be for problem with files sync but I haven't enough knowledge and experience with Docker. docker-compose logs have no errors.

Maybe somebody can help how to detect the reason? It starts once time but after reboot problem  occurs again...

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/webserver-apache/Dockerfile
        image: php:7.3.1-apache-stretch
        volumes:
            - "./docker/webserver-apache/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled:ro"
            - "./:/var/www/html"
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        networks:
            - dphptrainnet

    mariadb:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: mariadb:10.4.1
        networks:
            - dphptrainnet
        volumes:
            - ./env/mariadb/data:/var/lib/mysql            
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

networks:
    dphptrainnet:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.1-apache-stretch

# Setting up constants for an environment
ENV PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT    512M

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y curl vim git zip unzip

# Setting up httpd issues
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
RUN echo "127.0.0.1     dockertrain.local" >> /etc/hosts

WORKDIR "/var/www/html"

RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found only one working solution - reshare drive for Docker:
1. Disable shared disk, click Apply
2. Enable shared disk,  click Apply
3. Restart application - files were synced

But how I should detect there any problems with drive access? No errors, no logs....